# Text overflow not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My text overflow is not working properly, it just breaks line, what can i do to solve this?

[image]

```
            </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#"><img class="left-block img-responsive" src="genimage.png" width="160" height="160" alt="" /></a>
                <p style="width: 70px; text-overflow-mode: ellipsis; ">Any other Random Item Any other Random Item </p>
                <p>50 €</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but try `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/pjXKoX

Your question is pretty vague but you can check this one out
It's pretty adjustable via `<br>`

```
p{
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If you dont want a line break remove the `br` and just extend the width of the p element to show more words